# QEMU Networking Inside VirtualBox Guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization, qemu

So I have had QEMU networked before when it ran on a physical Ubuntu host, but I am trying to get it to communicate with my virtualized Ubuntu environment (i.e. a VirtualBox Ubuntu guest). Just to be absolutely clear on the setup see the below:

```
Windows - Physical Host
    Virtual Ubuntu - VirtualBox Guest with bridged networking.
        Debian - QEMU Guest running inside my virtualized Ubuntu environment.
```

Up to the my Ubuntu environment, networking works as I expect it to. When I launch my Debian image I use the following command:

```
qemu-system-i386 -netdev user,id=network0 -device e1000,netdev=network0 -hda debian_wheezy_i386_standard.qcow2
```

When Debian comes up, I am not able to ping my Ubuntu environment by IP and my Debian defaults to 127.0.1.1 which I read means Debian did not find a network. I have consulted the QEMU networking documentation and attempted the TAP networking, but ended up with the same result. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking#TAP.2FTUN_device

I also have tried a bridged connection via https://superuser.com/questions/1101100/how-to-bridge-networking-in-this-nested-virtualization-case and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge#With_iproute2 which actually broke my Ubuntu networking

I feel like I am close, but just can't quite get there. Any ideas?

Comment: did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Let me dig up my notes from when I posted this. I may have solved it.